# C function resulting in rounded number

Tags: r

**The case**

I have compiled shared library for dyn.loading into R. Then when I call the wrapper function in R I get result rounded with truncated part after decimal point. I am probably missing something well known as it is my first try to use .C function, but I can't find what is the cause of rounding. There is my code below.

**My C code**

```
#include <freesteam/steam_pT.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <R.h>

// gcc -Wall -fPIC -c Rsteam_h_pT_2.c -o  Rsteam_h_pT_2.o -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/R-2.14.0/lib/R/include -L/usr/local/lib -lfreesteam
// gcc -Wall -shared -o Rsteam_h_pT_2.so Rsteam_h_pT_2.o -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/R-2.14.0/lib/R/include -L/usr/local/lib -lfreesteam

// function
double steam_h_pT(double p, double T){
SteamState S = freesteam_set_pT(p, T);
double s = freesteam_h(S);
return s;
}


// wrapper
double steam_h_pT(double, double);
void steam_h_pT_R_wrapper(double *p, double *T, double *result) { *result = steam_h_pT(*p, *T); }
```

**My R function**

```
steam_h_pT <- function(p_Pa,T_K)
 {
 dyn.load('Rsteam_h_pT.so')
 # Call the C function
 returned_data = .C('steam_h_pT_R_wrapper', p=as.numeric(p_Pa), T= as.numeric(T_K), result=numeric(1))
 # Return the value of the result parameter
 return(returned_data$result)
 }
```

**My R session**

```
> steam_h_pT(100000,400)
[1] 2730398
> str(steam_h_pT(100000,400))
num 2730398
>
```

**Expected result from original code**

```
bash>./steam_h_pT 1e5 400
2730397.845968
```

**Now, why it gets rounded in R?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It the representation due to the `digits` argument to the `print` function. The number is still stored correctly.

```
2730397 + 0.845968
[1] 2730398
print(2730397 + 0.845968, digits=15)
[1] 2730397.845968
```

You can set the global default with `options(digits=15)`.

Answer (score 3):

That's just how R is formatting the number. The interop is fine and the value returned from C, and held by R has the full precision. It's just the display that is rounding the value.

```
x <- 2730397.845968
str(x)
```

outputs

```
num 2730398
```

Instead of `str` use a function that outputs more precision. For example:

```
print(steam_h_pT(100000,400), digits=16)
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  That is pretty confusing.